# Python. Как дополнять словари

Tags: python, словари

Всем привет) Столкнулся с проблемой. НЕ знаю как дополнять словарь.

```
list = {'сто': 100,
        'девяносто': 90,
        'двенадцать': 12,
        'пять': 5}
b = input('Число')
list['сто'] = b
for i, m in list.items():
        print(f'{i}: {m}')
```

Вывод

```
сто. 24
девяносто. 90
двенадцать. 12
пять. 5
```

Как можно сделать, что бы выводилось Сто : 100, и еще любое число(чтобы словарь не обновлялся, а добавлялся. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Словарь может содержать только один уникальный ключ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы словарь можно было пополнять, значения в нём должны быть списками. И я переименовал переменную со словарём, поскольку название `list` перекрывает встроенный тип `list`:

```
d = {'сто': [100],
        'девяносто': [90],
        'двенадцать': [12],
        'пять': [5]}
b = int(input('Число: '))
d['сто'].append(b)
for i, m in d.items():
        print(f'{i}: {",".join(map(str,m))}')
```

Вывод:

```
Число: 24
сто: 100,24
девяносто: 90
двенадцать: 12
пять: 5
```